# new discovery of retain ,or my misunderstanding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, retain

```
@interface DataMode : NSObject {

    NSString * name;
}

@property (retain) NSString * name;

- initWithName:(NSString * )name_;
@end


@implementation DataMode

@synthesize name;

- initWithName:(NSString * )name_
{
    if ([super init] != nil)
    {
        name = name_;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

@end


- (void) pressed:(id)sender
{

        NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zhang"];
        DataMode * a = [[DataMode alloc] initWithName:str];

        a.name;
        a.name;
        a.name;
        a.name;
        a.name;

        NSLog(@"name count:%d",[a.name retainCount]);

        [ a  release];

        NSLog(@"str count:%d",[str retainCount]);

}
@end

the output is
name count:7
str  count:7
```

but  the code don't leak any memory. I get the result in leaks and Active monitor tools.

begin I am surprise

because

SomeBody say "@property (retain) name;" eaual the below equal method.

```
- getname
{
    return name;
}
```

if that .it can't explain the above reslut of the output

I think the method should so

```
- getname
{
    [name retain];
    [name autorelease];
    return name;
}
```

so this can explain the high number 7,and not leak any memory.

this  is  my guess .  it take me too much time .I am shamed.

My understanding is  right ??? welcome your post and comment.

Comment: The mistake is that you are using `retainCount` to examine your memory management. Your code looks fine - you've balanced an alloc with a release. Instruments is telling you there are no leaks. That's all you need to worry about.

Comment: Actually I take issue with his constructor - he uses "name" instead of "self.name" and I believe this actually assigns it to internal variable, and not property (so it does not get retained). The only reason why it does not leak was because he used stringWithFormat.

Comment: Personally I think he should be using `name = [name_ copy]` in his initialiser, and release `name` in dealloc. Calling `self` in `init` functions is not generally a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

"SomeBody" is wrong. From [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2):

> If you specify `retain` or `copy` and do not specify `nonatomic`, then in a
>   reference-counted environment, a synthesized get accessor for an
>   object property uses a lock and retains and autoreleases the returned
>   value—the implementation will be similar to the following:
>
> ```
> [_internal lock]; // lock using an object-level lock
> id result = [[value retain] autorelease];
> [_internal unlock];
> return result;
> ```
>
> If you specify `nonatomic`, a synthesized accessor for an object property simply returns the value directly.

Answer (score 2):

1) `retainCount` is useless to you.

2) `retainCount` is useless to you.

3) yes, your properties should use retain+autorelease (there are a few cases where you can break this rule -- i'll not detail them here)

```
- (NSString *)name { return [[name retain] autorelease];
```

(note that this also is not threadsafe, nor are properties)

4) your NSString properties should be declared `copy` (not `retain`)

5) your `initWithName:` should *copy* the argument `name_` (assuming the property is copied)

```
name = [name_ copy];
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are new to the environment, you should most likely be using ARC and not worrying about this kind of stuff at all.

## retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

To repeat:

## retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

It is not useful for finding leaks as there are much better, more accurate, and less misleading tools available.

There are several problems with your code (but leaking isn't one of them):

- NSString* properties should be `copy`
- you don't use the property to set the string value in `init`, thus the DataMode instances are not retaining their strings.
- there is no dealloc method

Since you used `stringWithFormat:`, the constant string is turned into a non-constant string.   If you had used the constant string or `stringWithString:`, it'd be abazillionsomething (unsigned -1... UINT_MAX...).

In any case, you have:

- +1 for `stringWithString:`
- +1 for calling `a.name`, every time it is called

If Instruments is claiming a leak, post a screenshot.

Answer (score -2):

You shold type

```
- initWithName:(NSString * )name_
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        name = name_;
    }
    return self;
}
```